# Existence of a specific reordering bijection

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

Please consider a bijection $g:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ with following properties:

1. For all real series $(a_n)_{n\geq1}$, convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ implies convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{g(n)}$
2. Exist at least one real series $(c_n)_{c\geq1}$, that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n$ diverge, but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_{g(n)}$ converge.

If such bijection exist?

Comment: A detailed answer to your question can be found on the paper "Creating More Convergent Series" by Steven Krantz and Jeffery McNeal, which can be found [here](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/4145013?uid=3737664&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21101643556377).

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas I guess this qualifies to be turned into an answer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the request of the audience ;-):

"A detailed answer to your question can be found on the paper "Creating More Convergent Series" by Steven Krantz and Jeffery McNeal, which can be found [here](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/4145013?uid=3737664&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21101643556377)"